# Glide with context from ImageView

Tags: android, android-context, android-glide

Is it bad practice to use the following?

```
val imageView:ImageView = ...
val uri:Uri = ...
Glide.with(imageView.context).load(uri).into(imageView)
```

If it is bad practice, why?

Comment: no i don't think so.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Glide ultimately calls `getApplicationContext()` on whatever `Context` you pass there, so it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: @MikeM. i think in `Glide` you have to pass `getApplicationContext()` explicitly , i experienced some problem regarding the use of context , and ultimately i had to pas `getApplicationContext()` to the `Glide`

Comment: @AbdulKawee Are you sure that was your problem? https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.java#L223, https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.java#L689 In fact, that second link is the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @MikeM. you are right , i get it its calling `getApplicationContext()` , but again the mine problem was resolved by passing this , maybe it was because I was `preloading` images , and yeah you are right :)

Answer (score 2):

Glide is aware of it's context type: if it's an activity or application service it will, internally, because the image will become lifecycle aware and glide can optimise all kind of stuff knowing if onPause or onResume was called. Glide also allows you to use fragments and views from which it will take the context from.

It's not bad practice since your view's context it's the activity itself which will make your caching work just fine. Check this out for more details: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en